# How to sum the products price which belongs to same order Number? in codeigniter joins query

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

Actually, I am having two table, First one is sale Order Master while second is orders...
Now, on single order number I have two products in orders Table...
I want to sum the price of both product which are in orders table, on the **s_order_id**, which actually is coming in parameter.
Here is my **Model** code.

```
   function get_sums($id){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('sale_order_master');
$this->db->join('orders', 'orders.s_order_id=sale_order_master.s_order_id');
$this->db->where('orders.s_order_id',$id);
$this->db->select('SUM(subtotal) as total');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**left join** another table and **group by** orders.s_order_id

```
function get_sums($id){
    $this->db->select_sum('subtotal');
    $this->db->from('sale_order_master');
    $this->db->join('orders', 'orders.s_order_id=sale_order_master.s_order_id',"left");
    $this->db->where('orders.s_order_id',$id);
    $this->db->group_by('orders.s_order_id');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```